# Merging 2 tables is too slow

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

I have 2 similar tables that contain around 200.000 rows. I want to add the data from table 2 to table 1 if there is no similar data in table 1. I made a query that shows me what id's I can copy. But the query takes more than a day to execute, I was hoping to do this in +- 2 hours.

This is the query (All the data in the where are strings):

```
SELECT id
FROM   verwerkt2 v2
WHERE  0 = (SELECT Count(*)
            FROM   verwerkt
            WHERE  naam = v2.naam
                   AND postcode = v2.postcode
                   AND huisnummer = v2.huisnummer);
```

I get the data from a tool. That is why the data is not normalized.

Is there a faster way to do this?

Comment: Are you sure that your query return corrects ids to insert? It looks like it returns ids of rows that are the same

Comment: What do you mean by "if there is no similar data in table 1"?

Comment: support on what peterm said = =

Comment: @peterm Sorry, wrong query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try

```
INSERT INTO verwerkt (Naam, Postcode, Huisnummer, ...)
SELECT Naam, Postcode, Huisnummer, ... 
  FROM verwerkt2 v2
 WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
  SELECT *
    FROM verwerkt
   WHERE Naam       = v2.Naam
     AND Postcode   = v2.Postcode 
     AND Huisnummer = v2.Huisnummer        
);
```

Make sure that you have all necessary indices. In particular make sure that you have a covering index `(Naam, Postcode, Huisnummer)` in `verwerkt`

```
ALTER TABLE verwerkt ADD KEY (Naam, Postcode, Huisnummer);
```

Comment: It only takes 2 minutes now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In case the set of columns You are using for comparison (**naam** + **postcode** + **huisnummer**) supposed to be unique in target table, You should add a `UNIQUE` index on them

```
ALTER TABLE `verwerkt` ADD UNIQUE KEY `my_key` (naam,postcode,huisnummer);
```

and then simply

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO verwerkt SELECT * FROM verwerkt2;
```

This will eliminate the duplicates, and should be much faster

Answer (score 0):

You have to create indices on the fields used in the join: *Naam*, *Postcode* and *Huisnummer*. Or create a composed index. This will speed up your query by magnitudes.